# How to use plutil to replace data into a .plist file

Tags: bash, replace, find, command, key

I have 1 file test.plist:

[image]

I want to replace the AccountToken key with my values ​​some files above

```
AccountToken=$(cat AccountToken.txt)
```

I try this command but it doesn't work

```
plutil -key AccountToken -string $AccountToken test.plist
```

output :

```
<key>AccountToken</key>
    <string>
W50ZXJuYXRpb25hbE1vYmlsZUVx
</string>
```

I want 2 key string ==> data

please help, thanks all!!

Answer (score 1):

See [Editing Property Lists with plutil](https://scriptingosx.com/2016/11/editing-property-lists/). The option to replace a key is `-replace`, not `-key`.

```
plutil -replace AccountToken -string "$AccountToken" test.plist
```

Comment: this is the result 1 new value added last, the above remains the same:

<key>replace</key>
 <string>eyAiSW50ZXJuYXRpb25hbE1vYmlsZUVxdWlwbWVudElk</string>

Comment: That would happen if you used `-replace replace` instead of `-replace AccountToken`